# Substitution variable && not working in SQLcl

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

The "new" tool Oracle SQLcl is not interpreting "&&" correctly. Is there an option to correct this behavior?

```
Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue May 10 2022 18:17:49 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.15.0.1.0

SQL> def var=99
SQL> prompt &var &&var
99 &99
```

The expected answer would be: (using sqlplus)

```
SQL> def var=99
SQL> prompt &var &&var
99 99
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug.

You should log bugs to My Oracle Support, but I'll handle this one for you.

SQLcl debuted in 2014. Not sure if that's "new" or new.

Workaround: go download version 21.4 - I've confirmed it's working as expected there.

[image]